# cv2.cv.Round in OpenCV 3.2.0?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, rounding

Is there an implementation of cv2.cv.Round in OpenCV 3.2.0 ?
I have found out that the prefix cv2.cv was removed and instead cv2.argument is mostly used. But I can't find anything about Round in the docs. I know that cv2.cv.Round worked in earlier releases. Trying cv2.Round in 3.2.0 throws an error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Round'
```

Aswell this throws an error as expected because cv2.cv was removed.

```
cv2.cv.Round(133.4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

Comment: I guess it has been dropped in favor of python's builtin [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) and numpy's [`round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not `cv2.round` or `cv2.cv.round` or something else any more.

You can do this.

```
>>> sys.version
'3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'

>>> xxx = [-3.6,-3.5,-3.4,3.4,3.5,3.6]
>>> print(xxx)
[-3.6, -3.5, -3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6]

>>> list(map(round, xxx))
[-4, -4, -3, 3, 4, 4]

>>> func = lambda x: int(x+0.5) if x>0 else int(x-0.5)
>>> list(map(func, xxx))
[-4, -4, -3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: `func` does not handle negative numbers correctly.  For negative numbers, 0.5 should be subtracted, not added.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I am interested explicitly in the cv.Round function and if it is still available in 3.2.0!

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Round'
```

I have faced same issue and got solution just use directly `round Fun` no need `c2.round`, It is handled automatically, this is the basic Python function